# Handle location in a SQL database

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I am creating a cataloging system for rocks that come from all around the world. As part of this system, I need to handle the location of the where the rocks were found.

The problem is that the location needs to contain the country, a sub-item (e.g. State, Province), possibly another sub-item (e.g. County), then maybe a city, and then finally the mine/quarry/forest/etc that it was found in.

I don't think that I should allow the user to enter in the location every time in plain-text, as that runs the risk of multiple spellings for the same location. Also, because there are so many possibilities for the way location is structured (United states would be `USA:CALIFORNIA:ORANGE:LOS ANGELES` but Canada might be `CANADA:BRITISH COLOMBIA:VANCOUVER`) I don't know how to effectively store and query this information.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: At country level, go for [UN](https://unstats.un.org/unsd/methodology/m49/) or ISO country codes. For European countries, I'd suggest you use the [NUTS](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/nuts) classification. Something equivalent must exist for US and CA. I don't know if there is some equivalent for the rest of the world to that level of detail. Check also the [geonames database](http://www.geonames.org). Don't expect to be able to find a database that covers the whole planet earth with "city" detail (If you find it, let us know ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you aware of the "what3words" system??  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What3words

Or, how to address mail from the U.S. to anywhere in the world  - a problem similar to yours - https://blink.ucsd.edu/facilities/services/mail/international/addressing/index.html

I've seen geographical data represented with latitude/longitude or similar coordinates, plus a code representing how specific or accurate the coordinates are.

You could use coordinates together with a textual address.  The text is searchable but the coordinates -are-specific.

I think the proper way at the moment to store arbitrary text with markups for field identities - name of country / county / town etc. - is XML.  A similar effort of your own would be just re-inventing XML.

How does the Smithsonian do it?  Or is that where you're doing this?

Comment: No, nothing so grand as the Smithsonian, just a project for a grandparent. what3words wouldn't work for this project as it is somewhat important that the county/mine is listed. However, I think that by looking at the mailing information, I may have figured out the problem

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't say, what about meteors?  Don't some of them come from Mars??  Or the Moon.  While checking that (I was thinking about moon rocks, unlikely your grandparent has those unless s/he went there in person) I found something that BBC News has NOT TOLD ME, why??  http://www.dailystar.co.uk/news/latest-news/628478/Asteroid-Moon-explosion-NASA-warns-metor-Earth-collision-soon  (though it happened in 2013 so maybe they told me and I forgot).